# Using Hadoop Cluster Remotely

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-plugins

I have a web application and 1 remote clusters(It can be one or more). These cluster can be on different machines.
I want to perform following operations from my web application:

1 HDFS Actions :-

- Create New Directory
- Remove files from HDFS(Hadoop Distributed File System)
- List Files present on HDFS
- Load File onto the HDFS
- Unload File

2 Job Related Actions:-

- Submit Map Reduce Jobs
- View their status i.e. how much job has completed
- Time taken by the job to finish

I need a tool that can help me do these tasks from the web application - via an API, via  REST calls etc. I'm assuming that the tool will be running on the same machine( as the web application) and can point to a particular, remote cluster.

Though as a last option(*as there can be multiple,disparate clusters, it would be difficult to ensure that each of them has the plug-in,library etc. installed*), I'm wondering if there would be some Hadoop library,plug-in that rests on the cluster,allows access from remote machines and performs the mentioned tasks.

Answer (score 2):

The best framework which allows everything you have listed here is [Spring Data - Apache Hadoop](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/hadoop). This has Java Scripting API based implementations to do the following

```
1 HDFS Actions :-

Create New Directory
Remove files from HDFS(Hadoop Distributed File System)
List Files present on HDFS
Load File onto the HDFS
Unload File
```

As well spring scheduling based implementations to do the following

```
2 Job Related Actions:-

Submit Map Reduce Jobs
View their status i.e. how much job has comleted
Time taken by the job to finish
```

Comment: hi.....Thanks for the reply......if my remote clusters are on different machines then will this api gives me any methods so that i can run my map reduce jobs/perform hdfs actions on that cluster directly....

Comment: Yes, check the webinar available on the link so that you can better understand.